# Problema con impresora XPRINTER XP-58IIH

Tags: html, jquery

estoy haciendo un proyecto, con HTML y JQUERY, tengo este codigo

```
$("#imprimirBtn").on("click", function() {
    // Contenido HTML a imprimir
    var contenido = "<h1>Hola A Todos</h1>Feliz Navidad a todos, Jhonatan Pelaez";
    var ventanaImpresion = window.open('', '_blank');
    ventanaImpresion.document.write(contenido);
    ventanaImpresion.print();
    ventanaImpresion.onafterprint = function() {
        ventanaImpresion.close();
    };
  });
```

si me imprime, pero resulta que la tirilla sale demasiado larga para lo que estoy imprimiendo de prueba, no se si alguien tenga conocimiento de esto y me de una manito, muchas gracias